# Can I use a Django CMS placeholder inside an Apphook?

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm using Django 1.7.8, Django CMS 3.1.2 and djangocms-blog and I'm trying to add some banners to an apphooked page consisting in a group of blog entries.

I've tried to add placeholders to the template but I was unsuccessful.

Below is the code I'm using on the list. I've included a placeholder called header-banners and but doesn't show on the CMS frontend.

Is there some way to add a placeholder inside an apphooked page?

Thanks

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n cms_tags menu_tags %}

{% block meta %}
{% endblock meta %}

{% block subnavbar %}
<nav class="sub-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        {% language_chooser %}
    </div>
</nav>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="header-banner intro-banner blog-intro-banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="item">
                {% placeholder header-banners %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main-content blog-main-content">
    {% block content_blog %}{% endblock %}
    {% include "djangocms_blog/includes/blog_aside.html" %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it with `{% placeholder %}`, but try with `{% static_placeholder %}`.

See http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#static-placeholder.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution, but it works. Thank you